# fopen filename cross-platform

Tags: c++, linux, windows

How does the fopen API handle filename parameter on Windows and Linux?

***Background info for Linux***

> The fopen() function shall open the file whose pathname is the string pointed to by filename, and associates a stream with it.
>   http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html

This description does not really saying much about the pathname.

> A character string that is used to identify a file. In the context of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, a pathname consists of, at most, {PATH_MAX} bytes, including the terminating null byte. It has an optional beginning slash, followed by zero or more filenames separated by slashes. 
>   A pathname may optionally contain one or more trailing slashes. 
>   Multiple successive slashes are considered to be the same as one slash. 
>   http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_266

This appears to mean "/root/path/file" or "path/file" which I interpret to mean local file system including mounted points.

**Background info for Windows**

> fopen  accepts paths that are valid on the file system at the point of execution; 
>   fopen accepts UNC paths and paths that involve mapped network drives as long as the system that executes the code has access to the share or mapped drive at the time of execution.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx

This appears to mean local file system including mounted points and UNC paths.

The difference between Linux and Windows appears to be that Windows also allow access to a UNC path. Is this a correct assertion?

UNC is a network resource. Does the Windows implementation of fopen set any restriction on the type of network resource (share)? Does it support SMB, NFS, AFS, WebDAV, others?

Comment: Different platforms have different semantics for special paths, that's about sums up your background information?

Comment: As for your question, any valid file path, special or not, should be able to be opened with `fopen`. Not all functionality of the opened file may be supported depending on lower-level driver support, but if you can specify a path and file name, then `fopen` should be able to open it.

Comment: Joachim: The post was attempting to determine what constitute a valid path on the mentioned platforms. It appears UNC paths (a network resource) is not support by fopen on Linux. I wanted to know whether this was true. This means Linux needs to mount network file system in order to use them (I obviously do not use Linux).

Comment: Joachim: Secondly, how do I determine what is a legal UNC path? Does the underlying file system matter? The path could refer a NFS share or SMB Share og WebDAV share or ?

Comment: [UNC is a windows-only concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Naming_Convention#Uniform_Naming_Convention) so no it will not work in anything else than Windows.